# autocomplete using json object

Tags: javascript, json

I'e converted my list of products to a JSON object and now I want to use the JSON object with auto complete functionality.... I want to use only the JSON object for auto completion.. please help me out guys.

Comment: Are you using Javascript? Which library do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I did it with json data .... Json Rocks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm) jQuery plugin to get some basic, fast autocomplete in-browser.